# how do I rotate all bits to left and the last bit to the right in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have to shift all bits from x 1 position to the left and the first bit of the left to bit position 0 (most right). I was wondering what I am doing wrong and could you help me with it.

```
int rotateleft (int x);

int main ()
{      
    int getal,result;
    printf("Enter a number :\n");
    scanf("%i",&getal);
    result=rotateleft(getal);
    printf("result after rotation: %08x", result );
    return 0;
}

int rotateleft (int x)
{
    int rbit;
    rbit = x <<1;
return rbit;
}
```

Comment: You mean: you want to _rotate_ ?

Comment: There is no circular shift in C

Comment: @joop yes I meant rotate

Comment: guess u forgot to add return rbit in rotateleft

Comment: @ನಿಶಿತ್ if there were, this question would be worse than it already is.

Comment: @Deepthought Is this now correct or do I have to add something like return (value << shift) | (value >> (sizeof(value) * 8 - shift));

Comment: It's quite simple: Rather than trying to "cookbook" your way through it you *understand* what the `<<` operation does, and also understand what the `|` operation does, and maybe `&`.  If you *understand* these things then it's fairly obvious what to do -- you may not find the most clever way, but you can find a way.

Answer (score 5):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift#Implementing_circular_shifts):

```
unsigned int rotl(unsigned int value, int shift) {
    return (value << shift) | (value >> (sizeof(value) * CHAR_BIT - shift));
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `char` is 8 bits. Use `CHAR_BIT` rather than 8.

Comment: You can use `CHAR_BIT` instead. `char` has to be at least 8 bits wide according to the C standard, so I guess it's pretty safe.

Answer (score 2):

Before you do your shifting, get the top bit and save it. Then after the shifting you set that saved bit in the lowest bit in the (shifted) value.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t rotate(uint16_t num, uint16_t shBits);


int main(void) 
{   
   uint16_t num = 0x0088, res;
   printf("%x\n", num);
   res =  rotate(num, 3);
   printf("%x\n", res);
    return 0;
}

uint16_t rotate(uint16_t num, uint16_t shBits)
{
    shBits = ( (shBits < 0) ? -shBits : shBits) ; // make sure that n is not a negative number
    shBits = shBits % 16; // ensure that the shift value is less than 32

    // move shBits most significant bits to the right (LSBs)
    // 0x0088 >> (16 - 3) => 0000 0000 0000 0100
    // bits = 0000 0000 0000 0100
    uint16_t  bits = num >> (16 - shBits);

    // (num = 0x0088) >> 3 =>0x0011
    num >>= shBits;

    printf("num %x\n", num);
    printf("Bits %x\n", bits);
    shBits <<= num; // postion the shifted bints to the right location
    num |=shBits;
    printf("num %x\n", num);
    return (num); 
}
```

Input is `0x0088 (0000 0000 1000 1000)`
rotate by `3`
Output `0x0011 (0000 0000 0001 0001)`

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a `mask` to filer out the left most bit [usually MSB] and save it. Then apply required `shift` and put back the stored bit in the right most bit location [Usually LSB] shifted value.

In your code, there is one more thing to notice, there is no `return` statement in `int rotateleft (int x)` function. After doing all the computation correct, you'll not get the output. Add one `return rbit`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rotateleft (int x)
{
    int rbit;
    int bit;
    bit = !!(x & (1 << 31));
    x = x <<1;
    x |= bit;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift the number by 1 to the left then use the Bitwise OR to add the last bit to the start of the new number:

```
10000000000010010110100001100010 // i

00000000000100101101000011000100 // i << 1
00000000000000000000000000000001 // i >> 31
           |  | || |    ||   | |
00000000000100101101000011000101 // (i << 1) | (i >> 31)
```

So your function will be: [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/XPfMaE)

```
unsigned int rotateLeft(unsigned int i)
{
    unsigned int j = (i << 1) | (i >> 31);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: What if `i` is negative?

Comment: Funny, hadn't even realized that. Well then putting it in question form isn't going to do much, so here's the less polite form: dude, that's UB.

Comment: @harold Why is it UB?

Comment: Because, unfortunately, the standard says about left shifts: "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned." Also note that right-shifting a signed integer is implementation defined and very likely to be an arithmetic shift.

Comment: So i should use Unsigned int instead of int?

Comment: Yes, that would be better.